# facebook authentication in phonegap for ios

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, cordova

I'm trying to achieve following: I have facebook authentication on my web app. I want to return back to PhoneGap application after authentication is done.

The authentication flow works just fine. But returning to app should be done by providing a redirect url to facebook authentication URL. The problem is that I don't know what's the URL.

I've tried custom URL scheme, which works when authentication flow is executed in external Mobile Safari window. But in this case, the authentication is set to the Safari session, not for the Web App.

If external window is not used, but the authentication is done in Web App, the custom URL scheme won't work.

I have a hint this could be done with PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin. That's the last possible option I want to try

If the only possible solution is ChildBrowser, I haven't found any good tutorial or instructions how this should be done. Any advice on that?

please give solution if any one have better example

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap [released](http://phonegap.com/2011/08/30/get-the-new-phonegap-facebook-platform-plugin/) a plugin for connecting to facebook: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

Comment: I've tried using that plugin and can't recommend it. Badly maintained and buggy. It simply doesn't work on a wide range of android and Phonegap versions. It looks like it may have worked once upon a time, but not any more.

Comment: that plugin is a piece of crap